# React Map GL not rendering using create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would use React Mapbox GL using create react app helper, but I cannot render the map.

I've followed [This example](https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/tree/6.1-release/examples/controls), using that code it works, but I don't know how to build the App, so I'd prefer to use CRA.

In the console I don't have any errors, and yeah, the token is correct.

I've read somewhere that i have to use `<MapGL />` instead of `<MapGL> ... </MapGL>`, but as you will see, I do have other components inside the map, and even removing it, it gives me this error: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'context.viewport.zoom')`

How can I solve?

Here is my `App` component:

```
import MapGL, {
  Popup,
  NavigationControl,
  FullscreenControl,
  ScaleControl, GeolocateControl,

} from 'react-map-gl';

...

 const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    latitude: 40,
    longitude: -100,
    zoom: 3.5,
    bearing: 0,
    pitch: 0
  });
  const [popupInfo, setPopupInfo] = useState(null);


return (            
  <MapGL
    {...viewport}
     width="100%"
     height="100%"
     mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9"
     onViewportChange={setViewport}
     mapboxApiAccessToken={TOKEN}
   >
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading Events</div>}>
     <Pins onClick={setPopupInfo} />
    </Suspense>


    {
     popupInfo && (
     <Popup
      tipSize={5}
      anchor="top"
      longitude={popupInfo.location.longitude}
      latitude={popupInfo.location.latitude}
      closeOnClick={false}
      onClose={setPopupInfo}
     >
      <EventsInfo info={popupInfo} />
     </Popup>
     )}

      <GeolocateControl style={geolocateStyle} />
      <FullscreenControl style={fullscreenControlStyle} />
      <NavigationControl style={navStyle} />
      <ScaleControl style={scaleControlStyle} />

      <GeolocateControl
       style={geolocateStyle}
       positionOptions={positionOptions}
       trackUserLocation
       auto
      />
  </MapGL> 
)
```

Comment: Added snippet is fine. Could you create a jsfiddle or something like that to replicate this?

Comment: @Dolly, yeah I've then resolved, I forgot to incluse the style.css file in the Map component, so the DIV had height = 0